# Want to keep spaces in between tags while parsing xml file as well as when writing to a xml file in python

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

example:

```
<Amount currency = "100" sign = "D" >2000</Amount>
<Flag >Y</Flag>

After writing to xml it is changing to the below format:
<Amount currency="100" sign="D">2000</Amount>
<Flag>Y</Flag>
```

I want to preserve the spaces as shown in the example one

Comment: Those spaces are insignificant from an XML perspective. lxml will not preserve them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.